# ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$ numbers are given and divided into 2 groups and let the groups be $A$ and $B$.Prove that $A$ or $B$ contains $a,b,a+b$.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$ numbers are given and divided into 2 groups and let the groups be $A$ and $B$.Prove that $A$ or $B$ contains $a,b,a+b$.
$A$ contains none of the elements in the $B$.
$a$ is not equal to $b$

Is this problem can be solved?
If not ${1,2,3....n}$ what is lowest value of n?

Any help would be appreciated.
Well i tried dividing into groups and i didn't found any problem but i didn't check all possible groups.

Comment: Suppose $A$ has $n\geq5$ elements, and $B$ has $m$ elements. Say $A=\left\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\right\}$, with $a_1<\cdots<a_n$. Assume $a_1+a_2,a_1+a_3,\cdots,a_1+a_n,a_2+a_3,\cdots,a_{n-1}+a_n$ all belong to $B$. Then these are distinct elements. So $m\geq\frac{n(n-1)}2\geq 2n$. So $n+m\geq3n\geq15>10$, a contradiction. Hence some element $a_i+a_j\in A$.

Comment: I can't even find a way to divide the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ into two groups without one group containing $a,b,a+b$. Unless there's some condition you didn't bother to tell us about, like $a\ne b$?

Comment: $A$ contains none of the elements in $B$

Comment: In $1,2,3,4,5$ there is a contradiction$ (1,2,4) (3,5)$

Comment: But then A contains 1+1=2.